# C++ string() comparison with a c-string. WHY DOES THIS WORK?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, cstring

So this code is for a command input to be entered in any random order and it will return the value that comes after your input. Amt_Range is a digit checking function.

Why does this work. It should be able to due to the pointer comparison.??

More importantly what does the string() do. By my limited understanding the comparison should not work because a c style string is in the form '-' 't'. Thanks in advance!!

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

string dummy;
int tests = 0, quizzes = 0, assignments = 0, labs = 0, fin = 0;
int testweight = 0, quizweight = 0, assignweight = 0, labweight = 0, finweight = 0;
int counter = 1;

    if (argv[counter] == string("-t")) {
        dummy = argv[counter + 1];
        tests = Amt_Range(dummy, "tests");
        counter+=2;

    } else if (argv[counter] == string("-q")) {
        dummy = argv[counter + 1];
        quizzes = Amt_Range(dummy, "quizzes");
        counter+=2;


    } else if (argv[counter] == string("-a")) {
        dummy = argv[counter + 1];
        assignments = Amt_Range(dummy, "assignments");
        counter+=2;


    } else if (argv[counter] == string("-l")) {
        dummy = argv[counter + 1];
        labs = Amt_Range(dummy, "labs");
        counter+=2;


    } else if (argv[counter] == string("-f")) {
        dummy = argv[counter + 1];
        fin = Amt_Range(dummy, "whether there is a final");
        counter+=2;

    } else {
    cout << "wrong input NOW START OVER" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Luckily it's not comparing pointers (because it would never compare equal). Also, c strings are not "in the form '-' 't'". C strings are either `char const*` or `char(&)[N]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `operator==()` overload that kicks in is a free function in the `std` namespace.

```
namespace std { 
     bool operator==(std::string const&, std::string const&);
}
```

It takes the first argument by `const&` which means that a temporary is welcome.

A temporary happens to be creatable using the *implicit* conversion constructor `std::string(char const*)`. So, the overload applies.

> **UPDATE** *As uncovered in the comments, the standard actually declares*
>
> ```
>       bool operator==(const char*, std::string const&);
> ```
>
> *as an optimization in **[§21.4.8.2 operator==](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXLpt.png)**. However, the implicit conversion on the LHS is good to know about because it's a key ingredient in the language design with respect to operator overload (resolution)*

---

Now, the reason why the overload `bool std::operator==(std::string const&, std::string const&)` is even found during overload resolution is slightly subtle. This mechanism is known as Argument Dependent Lookup.

In this case, ADL works because the second argument is already a `std::string`, which has a type declared in the `std` namespace. Therefore, this namespace is searched for candidate `operator==` overloads

---

DISCLAIMER:

I've simplified the above. In reality the code in the standard library is much more generic still, and probably looks more like

```
namespace std { 
     template <typename Char, typename CharTraits, typename Alloc>
     bool operator==(std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits, Alloc> const&, std::basic_string<Char, CharTraits, Alloc>  const&) {
          // implementation...
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `std::operator==(char const *, std::string const&)`?

Comment: @Ohh I see, never mind, it implicitly converts the `char const*` to `std::string` via the `std::string`'s ctor...

Comment: @vsoftco You got it! (This, by the way might not be the most efficient thing to do, so it's good to be aware of it. Modern C++ libraries tend to prefer `explicit` conversion constructors for this reason - and some other pitfalls unrelated)

Comment: @Deduplicator, agree, first I though that the overloads exist, but found now they don't.

Comment: Mmm. Let me check they don't actually exist :) I might just not remember

Comment: @sehe, it seems they exist actually, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp Would have been a bit weird not to, due to performance issues, as Deduplicator mentioned.

Comment: Okay. I've updated my answer to be more accurate in this particular case, though I kept my broader explanation involving implicit conversions on the LHS operand, because I think it will aid understanding to those learning C++.

Comment: Gotta say that I am a bit confused about the ADL. Why ADL here? The OP seems to have an `using namespace std;` already, so he's not calling `operator==(const char*, std::string)`. Sorry for the long line of comments, would like to understand what you meant by ADL kicking in here.

Comment: @vsoftco I have a blind spot for `using namespace std`. It shouldn't be used, so I assume it isn't used. In real life, production quality code, ADL would kick in here. (Just as in `std::cout << "hello world\n";` for that matter)

Comment: OK :) +1, great answer anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure it's wise to name any standard library function "an optimization".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit agreed. I pondered it. What would you call it, though?

Comment: ---Probably something along the lines of "for utility" or "for convenience". I dunno, something like that.--- Actually I guess they don't really fit; I've only just realised _why_ you were circling the "optimisation" route. Not sure I can come up with anything better.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the standard (C++14):

> #### 21.3 String classes `[string.classes]`
>
> ```
> template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
> bool operator==(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
>     const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs) noexcept;
> template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
> bool operator==(const charT* lhs, const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
> template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
> bool operator==(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs, const charT* rhs);
> ```
>
> [... same for `!=` `<` `>` `<=` `>=`]

Or look in this section:

> #### 21.4.8.2 `operator==` `[string::operator==]`

So there is an exact match, which is found in namespace `std` (would use ADL (argument-dependent lookup, counting the arguments namespaces as associated namespaces and searching them too) if there was no using-directive in scope).

BTW: I'm a bit disappointed that two `std::basic_string`s differing only in allocator-type cannot be compared (template-arguments must match exactly)...
A quick demo on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01788a718178c6d2

Comment: Differently allocated strings _can_ be compared, as long as they have implicit conversions. I _know_ I've compared heterogenous strings in shared memory and otherwise before. Let me see how that actually worked (if I can still find it)

Comment: Must template-arguments not match exactly?

Comment: I will look up the mechanics. But, you know what you know, and I already said what I think is the catch here (implicit conversion?). Hang on for a moment please

Comment: @sehe: See here for demonstration: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01788a718178c6d2

Comment: Patience... [you don't have it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79ce7cc2dfd22d13) (fixed) :) Anyhoops, seems I misremembered, and it was for `operator<` anyways (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26454275/85371)). That's the same mixed `char*` vs. `basic_string<...>` overloading. Note however, not deducing a different set of template arguments enables implicit conversions to the `basic_string` type of the argument that matches, so that might be the **key** reason to not deduce different sets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65246/discussion-between-sehe-and-deduplicator).