# want to efficiently overcome mismatch between key types in a map in Boost.Interprocess shared memory

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I'm creating a map (from string to string in this example) in shared memory using Boost.Interprocess.
The compiler seems to want to force me, during retrieval from the map, to allocate memory in the
managed segment just to (unnecessarily) contain the query term.

I'd like to be able
to look up values in a shared map more efficiently, by matching the map's keys against instances that are already in non-shared memory, without performing this extra allocation.  But it's
refusing to compile if I try to use a `std::string` or `const char *` as the argument to the map's `find` method.
(see compiler error messages at bottom).

Do I need to define some sort of
comparator method between my shared-memory key type and its non-shared equivalent (`std::string` in this example)? If so, what should
this look like and how should I make the map use it?   If not, what should I do?

Here's the code, followed by the compiler errors.  The problem is towards the bottom of `main()`.

```
// shmap2.cpp

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>

//Typedefs of allocators and containers
namespace Shared
{
    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory
        Segment;

    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager
        SegmentManager;

    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< void, SegmentManager >
        Allocator;

    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< char, SegmentManager >
        CharAllocator;

    typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string< char, std::char_traits< char >, CharAllocator > 
        String;

    typedef std::less< String >
        StringComparator;

    // Definition of the shared map from String to String
    // (To avoid confusion, let's strictly use Python-like definitions of "key", "value" and "item")
    typedef std::pair< const String, String >
        MapItem;

    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< MapItem, SegmentManager >
        MapItemAllocator;

    typedef boost::interprocess::map< String, String, StringComparator, MapItemAllocator >
        Map;
}

int main( void )
{
    struct shm_remove
    {
        shm_remove() { boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove( "MySharedMemory" ); }
        ~shm_remove(){ boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove( "MySharedMemory" ); }
    } remover;

    // Create shared memory
    Shared::Segment seg( boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536 );

    // An allocator instance that can be converted to any allocator< T, Shared::SegmentManager > type
    Shared::Allocator alloc( seg.get_segment_manager() );

    // An instance of the string comparator, to construct the map
    Shared::StringComparator cmp;

    // Construct the shared memory map
    Shared::Map * myMapPtr = seg.construct< Shared::Map >( "myMap" )( cmp, alloc );

    // Here's the problem:

    // std::string key( "foo" );            // Compilation fails if you use this.
    // char key[] = "foo";                  // Compilation fails if you use this.
    Shared::String key( "foo", alloc );     // This the only version I can get to work.
                                            // But it forces you to create a copy of
                                            // the key you are searching for, in
                                            // the managed segment.

    // This is the point of the exercise:
    Shared::Map::iterator it = myMapPtr->find( key );

    return 0;
}
```

With a `std::string` as the `key`:

```
$ g++ -o shmap2 -D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB  -I ../boost_1_57_0  shmap2.cpp
shmap2.cpp:79:40: error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
                Shared::Map::iterator it = myMapPtr->find( key );
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
../boost_1_57_0/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:1089:13: note: candidate function not
      viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char,
      char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'const key_type' (aka 'const
      boost::container::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      boost::interprocess::allocator<char, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char,
      boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,
      boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long, unsigned long, 0>, 0>, iset_index> >
      >') for 1st argument
   iterator find(const key_type& k)
            ^
../boost_1_57_0/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:1092:19: note: candidate function not
      viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char,
      char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'const key_type' (aka 'const
      boost::container::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      boost::interprocess::allocator<char, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char,
      boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,
      boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long, unsigned long, 0>, 0>, iset_index> >
      >') for 1st argument
   const_iterator find(const key_type& k) const
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

With `const char *` as the `key`:

```
$ g++ -o shmap2 -D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB  -I ../boost_1_57_0  shmap2.cpp
In file included from shmap2.cpp:17:
In file included from ../boost_1_57_0/boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp:19:
../boost_1_57_0/boost/container/string.hpp:676:59: error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of 'allocator_type' (aka 'boost::interprocess::allocator<char,
      boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char,
      boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,
      boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long, unsigned long, 0>, 0>, iset_index> >')
   basic_string(const CharT* s, const allocator_type& a = allocator_type())
                                                          ^
shmap2.cpp:79:46: note: in instantiation of default function argument expression for
      'basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, boost::interprocess::allocator<char,
      boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char,
      boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,
      boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long, unsigned long, 0>, 0>, iset_index> > >'
      required here
                Shared::Map::iterator it = myMapPtr->find( key );
                                                           ^
../boost_1_57_0/boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp:140:4: note: candidate
      constructor template not viable: requires single argument 'other', but no
      arguments were provided
   allocator(const allocator<T2, SegmentManager> &other)
   ^
../boost_1_57_0/boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp:129:4: note: candidate
     constructor not viable: requires single argument 'segment_mngr', but no arguments
     were provided
   allocator(segment_manager *segment_mngr)
   ^
../boost_1_57_0/boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp:134:4: note: candidate
     constructor not viable: requires single argument 'other', but no arguments were
     provided
   allocator(const allocator &other)
   ^
1 error generated.
```

**UPDATE:** following the suggestion of sehe, below, I tried replacing

```
typedef std::less< String >
    StringComparator;
```

with

```
typedef struct
{
    template< typename T, typename U >
    bool operator()( const T & t, const U & u )
        const { return t < u; }
} StringComparator;
```

but got the same two compiler errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom comparator

```
   struct MyLess {
        template <typename T, typename U>
            bool operator()(const T&t, const U&u) const
        {
            return t<u;
        }
    };
```

In your code you can just typedef it as `StringComparator`

**UPDATE** To the comments

---

### Multi Index To The Rescue

If you want to replace the `std::map`/`boost::container::map` with a Boost Multi Index container (which supports lookup by `CompatibleKey`), here's a demo of how to do it:

I've borrowed some of the idea's from the documentation section **[Emulating standard containers with `multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html#emulate_assoc_containers)**.

Note that `std::string` as the lookup key still won't work, but you can easily use `.c_strio()` in that event.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6f17ba75a59f064)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

namespace emulation {
    template <typename T1,typename T2,typename Alloc>
        struct mutable_pair
        {
            typedef T1 first_type;
            typedef T2 second_type;

            mutable_pair(Alloc alloc):first(T1(alloc)),second(T2(alloc)){}
            mutable_pair(const T1& f,const T2& s):first(f),second(s){}
            mutable_pair(const std::pair<T1,T2>& p):first(p.first),second(p.second){}

            T1         first;
            mutable T2 second;
        };

    using namespace boost::multi_index;

    template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator, typename Element = mutable_pair<Key, T, Allocator> >
        using map = multi_index_container<
            Element,
            indexed_by<
                ordered_unique<member<Element,Key,&Element::first>,Compare>
            >,
            typename Allocator::template rebind<Element>::other
        >;

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator, typename Element = mutable_pair<Key, T, Allocator> >
    using multimap = multi_index_container<
        Element,
        indexed_by<
            ordered_non_unique<member<Element,Key,&Element::first>,Compare>
        >,
        typename Allocator::template rebind<Element>::other
    >;

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator> 
      struct wrap_map : map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator> {
          typedef map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator> base_type;
          typedef typename base_type::template nth_index<0>::type index_type;

          wrap_map(Allocator alloc) : base_type({}, alloc)
          {
          }

          wrap_map(Compare cmp, Allocator alloc) : base_type(
                  typename base_type::ctor_args_list{
                    typename index_type::ctor_args { typename index_type::key_from_value {}, cmp }
                  },
                  alloc)
          {
          }
      };
}

// Typedefs of allocators and containers
namespace Shared {
    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory Segment;
    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager SegmentManager;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<void, SegmentManager> Allocator;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, SegmentManager> CharAllocator;
    typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> String;

    struct MyLess {
        template <typename T, typename U> bool operator()(const T &t, const U &u) const { return t < u; }
    };
    typedef MyLess StringComparator;


    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, SegmentManager> StringAlloc;
    typedef emulation::mutable_pair<const String, String, StringAlloc> MapItem;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<MapItem, SegmentManager> MapItemAllocator;
    typedef emulation::wrap_map<String, String, StringComparator, MapItemAllocator> Map;
}

int main(void) {
    struct shm_remove {
        shm_remove() { boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
        ~shm_remove() { boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;

    // Create shared memory
    Shared::Segment seg(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
    Shared::Allocator alloc(seg.get_segment_manager());

    // An instance of the string comparator, to construct the map
    Shared::StringComparator cmp;

    // Construct the shared memory map
    Shared::Map *myMapPtr = seg.construct<Shared::Map>("myMap")(cmp, alloc);

    myMapPtr->emplace(Shared::String("foo", alloc), Shared::String("bar", alloc));
    myMapPtr->emplace(Shared::String("goo", alloc), Shared::String("car", alloc));
    myMapPtr->emplace(Shared::String("hoo", alloc), Shared::String("dar", alloc));

    Shared::String key("foo", alloc);

    // This is the point of the exercise:
    auto it = myMapPtr->find(key);

    if (it!=myMapPtr->end())
        std::cout << "Found: '" << it->first << "' -> '" << it->second << "'\n";

    // this is now okay too
    char szkey[] = "foo";
    it = myMapPtr->find(szkey);
    if (it!=myMapPtr->end())
        std::cout << "Found: '" << it->first << "' -> '" << it->second << "'\n";

    // this is now okay too
    std::string skey("foo");
    it = myMapPtr->find(skey.c_str());
    if (it!=myMapPtr->end())
        std::cout << "Found: '" << it->first << "' -> '" << it->second << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Found: 'foo' -> 'bar'
Found: 'foo' -> 'bar'
Found: 'foo' -> 'bar'
```

---

### Scoped Allocators For Extra Awesomesauce?

Now, interestingly, Boost Container supports Scoped Allocators, so you could do away with the repeated passing of the allocators, however, Boost Multi Index sadly doesn't support it *fully*. Here's a halfway approach that's about as far as I could get it (still somewhat user friendlier):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa600130380cca2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>

#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

namespace emulation {
    template <typename T1,typename T2,typename Alloc>
        struct mutable_pair
        {
            typedef Alloc allocator_type;
            typedef T1 first_type;
            typedef T2 second_type;

            mutable_pair(Alloc alloc):first(T1(alloc)),second(T2(alloc)){}
            mutable_pair(const T1& f,const T2& s):first(f),second(s){}
            mutable_pair(const std::pair<T1,T2>& p):first(p.first),second(p.second){}

            template <typename U, typename V, typename Alloc2>
            mutable_pair(const U& f,const V& s, Alloc2 alloc):first(f, alloc),second(s, alloc){}

            T1         first;
            mutable T2 second;
        };

    using namespace boost::multi_index;

    template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator, typename Element = mutable_pair<Key, T, Allocator> >
        using map = multi_index_container<
            Element,
            indexed_by<
                ordered_unique<member<Element,Key,&Element::first>,Compare>
            >,
            typename Allocator::template rebind<Element>::other
        >;

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator, typename Element = mutable_pair<Key, T, Allocator> >
    using multimap = multi_index_container<
        Element,
        indexed_by<
            ordered_non_unique<member<Element,Key,&Element::first>,Compare>
        >,
        typename Allocator::template rebind<Element>::other
    >;

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator> 
      struct wrap_map : map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator> {
          typedef map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator> base_type;
          typedef typename base_type::template nth_index<0>::type index_type;

          wrap_map(Allocator alloc) : base_type({}, alloc)
          { 
          }

          wrap_map(Compare cmp, Allocator alloc) : base_type(
                  typename base_type::ctor_args_list{
                    typename index_type::ctor_args { typename index_type::key_from_value {}, cmp }
                  },
                  alloc)
          { 
          }
      };
}


// Typedefs of allocators and containers
namespace Shared {
    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory Segment;
    typedef Segment::segment_manager SegmentManager;
    typedef boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<boost::interprocess::allocator<void, SegmentManager> > Allocator;

    typedef Allocator::rebind<char>::other CharAllocator;
    typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> String;

    struct MyLess {
        template <typename T, typename U> bool operator()(const T &t, const U &u) const { return t < u; }
    };
    typedef MyLess StringComparator;

    typedef emulation::mutable_pair<String, String, CharAllocator> MapItem;
    typedef Allocator::rebind<MapItem>::other MapItemAllocator;
    typedef emulation::wrap_map<String, String, StringComparator, MapItemAllocator> Map;
}

int main(void) {
    struct shm_remove {
        shm_remove() { boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
        ~shm_remove() { boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;

    // Create shared memory
    Shared::Segment seg(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
    Shared::Allocator alloc(seg.get_segment_manager());

    // An instance of the string comparator, to construct the map
    Shared::StringComparator cmp;

    // Construct the shared memory map
    Shared::Map *myMapPtr = seg.construct<Shared::Map>("myMap")(cmp, alloc);

    myMapPtr->emplace("foo", "bar", alloc);
    myMapPtr->emplace("goo", "car", alloc);
    myMapPtr->emplace("hoo", "dar", alloc);

    // This the only version I can get to work.  But it forces you to create a
    // copy of the key you are searching for, in the managed segment.
    Shared::String key("foo", alloc);     

    // This is the point of the exercise:
    auto it = myMapPtr->find(key);

    if (it!=myMapPtr->end())
        std::cout << "Found: '" << it->first << "' -> '" << it->second << "'\n";

    // this is now okay too
    char szkey[] = "foo";
    it = myMapPtr->find(szkey);
    if (it!=myMapPtr->end())
        std::cout << "Found: '" << it->first << "' -> '" << it->second << "'\n";

    // this is now okay too
    std::string skey("foo");
    it = myMapPtr->find(skey.c_str());
    if (it!=myMapPtr->end())
        std::cout << "Found: '" << it->first << "' -> '" << it->second << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Also printing

```
Found: 'foo' -> 'bar'
Found: 'foo' -> 'bar'
Found: 'foo' -> 'bar'
```

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm misremembering something here. Lookup by "CompatibleKey" might not be a feature in Boost's `map`. In that case, refer to e.g. Boost MultiIndex **[back-story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453696/how-to-overload-the-assignment-operator-for-strings-that-use-custom-allocator/26454275#comment41549780_26454275)**. It's not hard to "configure" it in `std::map` similar mode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  As you suspected, this doesn't seem to make a difference with `map` (see update at end of question). I'm not familiar with MultiIndex yet so the code in the other thread looks way beyond my comprehension (even my understanding of `MyLess` is superficial: I understand what it's doing at surface level but the deeper *why* of it is currently beyond me). I'll take a look at Boost.MultiIndex.

Comment: @jez I've just added two takes on it (actually, a third one: if you don't need the stateful comparator passed during construction, there's **[no need for the `wrap_map` helper type](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3f3376faa3549fa)** that was just there to make the constructor call compatible)

Comment: Wow, this is impressive.  I feel like a caveman who's been given a Zippo.  I'll study this to see if I can figure out how it works and try not to burn myself too badly.  Thanks for distilling it down into an accessible example.  Initially I got a lot of compiler errors but finally figured out that I needed to compile with the `-std=c++11` flag to g++ on my mac.  On Windows however, for various tedious reasons, I've been working with MSVC 2010. Is this likely to be possible without the C++11 extensions? Or are things like `using map = multi_index_container....` integral to the way it works?

Comment: *+1* for effort and technical detail.

Comment: @jez Here's c++03 version where the template aliases have been replaced by run-of-the-mill type functions (`map_gen` and `multi_map_gen`): **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24f12d4f7219c5de)**

Comment: @sehe  that is awesome.  Thanks, that really helps with the project as well as will my understanding of C++11. Me go light fire now.

Comment: @sehe I've added an answer, below, that aimed to generalize your last solution to cases in which the key and value classes differ. It seemed like `T1(alloc)` and `T2(alloc)` didn't make sense in that context, but to my surprise it compiles either way.  I don't really understand, but I guess I'm going to work on the assumption that it's more maintainable/future-proof to allow two different allocator types in the definitions.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following is adapted from the C++03-compatible code linked from @sehe's comment on vis own answer.  Although I don't really know what I'm doing, I've generalized it in the way that seemed fitting for maps whose keys are not of the same type as their mapped values, by adding a second allocator type to the `mutable_pair` and `map_gen` definitions.  I've made it clear which namespace everything comes from and removed the `multimap_gen` definition for brevity.   It compiles to allow `map< string vector<int> >`-type objects in shared memory to be queried with `const char *`.

The one thing I wasn't sure of was whether `ValueType` needs to make an appearance in the `rebind` line, but it seems to compile and work as is so far...

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

namespace sehe
{
    template < typename T1, typename T2, typename Alloc1, typename Alloc2 >
        struct mutable_pair
        {
            typedef T1 first_type;
            typedef T2 second_type;

            mutable_pair( Alloc1 alloc1, Alloc2 alloc2 ) : first( T1( alloc1 ) ), second( T2( alloc2 ) ) {}
            mutable_pair( const T1 & f, const T2 & s ) : first( f ), second( s ) {}
            mutable_pair( const std::pair< T1, T2 > & p ) : first( p.first ), second( p.second ) {}

            T1         first;
            mutable T2 second;
        };


    template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType, typename Compare, typename KeyAllocator, typename ValueAllocator, typename Element = mutable_pair< KeyType, ValueType, KeyAllocator, ValueAllocator > >
        struct map_gen
        {
            typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container
            <
                Element,
                boost::multi_index::indexed_by
                <
                    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique< boost::multi_index::member< Element, KeyType, &Element::first >, Compare >
                >,
                typename KeyAllocator::template rebind<Element>::other
            > type;
        };

    typedef struct {
        template <typename T, typename U> bool operator()(const T &t, const U &u) const { return t < u; }
    } Comparator;

}

// Typedefs of allocators and containers
namespace Shared
{
    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory Segment;
    typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager SegmentManager;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<void, SegmentManager> Allocator;


    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, SegmentManager> CharAlloc;
    typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAlloc> String;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< String, SegmentManager > StringAlloc;

    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< int, SegmentManager > IntAlloc;
    typedef boost::interprocess::vector< int, IntAlloc > IntVector;
    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< IntVector, SegmentManager > IntVectorAlloc;

    typedef sehe::map_gen< String, String,    sehe::Comparator, StringAlloc, StringAlloc >::type StringStringMap;
    typedef sehe::map_gen< String, IntVector, sehe::Comparator, StringAlloc, IntVectorAlloc >::type StringIntVectorMap;
}
```

Comment: `ValueType` is already part of the `Element` (so, `ValueType` is an ambiguous in a map context: it's a "mapped type" really). Also, the allocator dance is not required: allocators have implicit conversion constructors: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96bf6c8daf40e767)** [...]

Comment: [...] in fact the only reason we are passing allocators around is their state (namely, the `segment_manager`). All the allocator instances, regardless of type, share that state. This also leads to the **one exception** where you would actually want to pass separate allocators: when you want to use _different_ segment managers for the various components. That's an interesting thought, but doesn't come up often in practice.