# Is there a robust implementation of condition_variable and mutex that can be stored in shared memory on Windows?

Tags: boost, mutex, interprocess

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991510/why-does-boosts-interprocess-condition-deadlock-in-notify-one/45044997#45044997) question, use of boost's interprocess_mutex and interproces condition_variable may result in a deadlock if the process holding the mutex crashes.
This is because boost's mutex is not a kernel object and therefore is not automatically released when the process holding it exits.
Is there a way in boost to use interprocess conditional variables with the mutex returned by a call to CreateMutex?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179685/how-do-i-take-ownership-of-an-abandoned-boostinterprocessinterprocess-mutex/1179766#1179766

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  

An interprocess mechanism that does not handle a crash in one of the processes? 
I would have expected better from boost.

Comment: TBH it's application defined what should be the behaviour. Unless the OS supports robust IPC synchronization mechanisms, which I doubt. And if it does: use that ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CreateSemaphore()` directly to implement condvars across multiple processes. You don't need to use Boost condvars. Windows provides a very rich set of well defined, fairly correct, named machine-wide synchronisation objects. Use those instead.

Comment: Implementing condvars is not a simple matter and involves much more than calling CreateSemaphore.

Comment: Boost.Thread's condvar implementation is implemented on win32 using win32 semaphores which are not broken like the POSIX ones. Simply clone that implementation. Should be done within an hour.

Comment: Boost.Interprocess author here. Using semaphores will not fix the issue. If a process dies while using a semaphore implementing a condition variable, the other process won't notice it. The exception are named mutexes, that can return WAIT_ABANDONED when the owner dies. Semaphores, by definition, have no owner, so if a process is waiting another one to signal a semaphore and the signaller dies, there is no notification by the kernel.