# Finding an element in boost::bimaps::bimap by different type than bimap key type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bimap

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/bimap/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_multiset_of.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::bimaps;
using namespace boost;

struct Example
{
    uint64_t id;
};

struct ExampleHash
{
    uint64_t operator()(const Example& item) const
    {
        return item.id;
    }

    uint64_t operator()(const uint64_t item) const
    {
        return item;
    }
};

struct ExampleEq
{
    bool operator()(const Example& l, const Example& r) const
    {
        return l.id == r.id;
    }

    bool operator()(const uint64_t l, const Example& r) const
    {
       return l == r.id;
    }

    bool operator()(const Example& l, const uint64_t r) const
    {
        return operator()(r, l);
    }
};

using BM = bimaps::bimap<
    unordered_multiset_of<std::string>,
    unordered_multiset_of<Example, ExampleHash, ExampleEq>
>;

int main() {
    BM bm;
    bm.insert(BM::value_type("First", Example{1}));

    auto it = bm.right.find(1u);

    return 0;
}
```

According to [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/reference/unordered_set_of_reference.html#boost_bimap.reference.unordered_set_of_reference.unordered___multi__set_of_views.lookup)

```
template< class CompatibleKey >
iterator find(const CompatibleKey & x);
```

*A type CompatibleKey is said to be a compatible key of (Hash, Pred) if (CompatibleKey, Hash, Pred) is a compatible extension of (Hash, Pred). This implies that Hash and Pred accept arguments of type CompatibleKey, which usually means they have several overloads of their corresponding operator() member functions.*

So I thought that `auto it = bm.right.find(1u);` will work. Unfortunately this generates an compilation error:

```
error: no match for call to (boost::bimaps::container_adaptor::detail::key_to_base_identity<Example, const Example>) (const long unsigned int&)
```

My question is if it is even possible to use CompatibleKey of a diffrent type than bimap key type? I have already tried to go over the boost headers, unfortunately the implmentation is too complicated for me to comprehend what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your reading that the description *seemed* to suggest that this usage should be allowed.

However after *long* reading and testing, I cannot see how the code would actually support it. What's more, there's this signature:

```
template< class CompatibleKey >
  bool replace_key(iterator position, const CompatibleKey & x);
```

Which according to its docs requires "CompatibleKey can be assigned to key_type". That's a clear contradiction of the "minimal requirements" seen earlier.

After coming to the conclusion that apparently it can't work, I remembered seeing the same before...:

- [want to efficiently overcome mismatch between key types in a map in Boost.Interprocess shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328835/want-to-efficiently-overcome-mismatch-between-key-types-in-a-map-in-boost-interp/27330042#27330042)
- The comments lead me back to [How to overload the assignment operator for strings that use custom allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453696/how-to-overload-the-assignment-operator-for-strings-that-use-custom-allocator/26454275#26454275), which also had some comments leading to
- https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/10678 Which says, specifically:

> **WONTFIX** In order to deal with compatible keys for hashed indices, you'd need
>   not only transparent equality comparison but also some sort of
>   transparent hash functor such as
>
> ```
> struct generic_hash
> {
>   template<typename T>
>   std::size_t operator()(const T& x)const
>   {
>      boost::hash<T> h;
>      return h(x);
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> but using this is tricky (and dangerous):
>
> ```
> multi_index_container<
>   std::string,
>   indexed_by<
>     hashed_unique<identity<std::string>,generic_hash,std::less<void>>
>   >
> > c{"hello"};
>
> std::cout<<*(c.find("hello"))<<"\n"; // crash
> ```
>
> The reason for the problem is: hashing a `std::string` does not yield
>   the same value has hashing a const char*, so `c.find("hello")` does
>   not find the string `"hello"`. This is why ​[N3657](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm) applies only to
>   associative containers and has not been extended to unordered
>   associative containers.
>
> As for `std::less<void>`, I'm sympathetic to your proposal but would
>   prefer to go in line with the standard, which decided for
>   `std::less<void>` to be explicitly provided by the user rather than
>   the default.

I was a little embarrassed to find my own comment from 2014 there :)

Comment: (PS. In case it wasn't clear, [Boost Multi Index underlies Boost Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/bimap_and_boost.html#boost_bimap.bimap_and_boost.bimap_and_multiindex))

Comment: This looks like a bug in Boost.Bimap. The requirement that `CompatibleKey` can be assigned to `key_type` doesn't apply to `find` (or at least docs don't mention it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Boost.Bimap, but the equivalent construct using Boost.MultiIndex works as intended:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19043317572a6366)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace boost;

struct Example
{
    uint64_t id;
};

struct ExampleHash
{
    uint64_t operator()(const Example& item) const
    {
        return item.id;
    }

    uint64_t operator()(const uint64_t item) const
    {
        return item;
    }
};

struct ExampleEq
{
    bool operator()(const Example& l, const Example& r) const
    {
        return l.id == r.id;
    }

    bool operator()(const uint64_t l, const Example& r) const
    {
       return l == r.id;
    }

    bool operator()(const Example& l, const uint64_t r) const
    {
        return operator()(r, l);
    }
};

using BM_value_type=std::pair<std::string,Example>;

using BM = multi_index_container<
    BM_value_type,
    indexed_by<
        hashed_non_unique<member<BM_value_type, std::string, &BM_value_type::first>>,
        hashed_non_unique<
          member<BM_value_type,Example,&BM_value_type::second>,
          ExampleHash,ExampleEq
        >
    >
>;

int main() {
    BM bm;
    bm.insert(BM::value_type("First", Example{1}));

    auto it = bm.get<1>().find(1u);

    std::cout<<it->second.id<<"\n"; // 1

    return 0;
}
```

You might want to file a ticket with Boost.Bimap (this definitely looks like a bug to me).